# What happened to old high scores on the updated Imagine Dragons maps?

Tags: beat-saber

[Beat Saber v1.28.0](https://store.steampowered.com/app/2271510/Beat_Saber__Imagine_Dragons__Bones/) updated the Imagine Dragons Song Pack to change the layouts of existing songs. Surprisingly, it looks like old high scores from the previous versions weren't wiped from the leaderboard.

How were old high scores translated to the new updated maps? Is there any way to tell if a score was set on the old or new version of the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Beat Saber v1.31.0](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/620980/view/3674423070127121444), the original 'legacy' beatmaps have been re-added with their own separate leaderboards.

Looking at my own scores, it seems high scores on 'legacy' maps revamped prior to v1.31.0 (Imagine Dragons, Panic At the Disco) were merged into the new leaderboards, while high scores on maps revamped after the update (Linkin Park) were preserved on the 'legacy' leaderboards.

[image: Legacy scores for Believer]